# Make an Independent Popup in Qt Quick

Tags: qt, qml

I have an app which is small in terms of width and height, I want a popup to show when a button is clicked. Problem is the popup is larger than the app window and when i open it, it scales down and looks weird

**APP**

[image: f572d9c0-7ff4-4797-b5de-84c68b456dc4-image.png]

**APP WITH POPUP**

[image: 7824844e-c884-484a-9f33-e14fb00c2d73-image.png]

**POPUP CONTENT IN DESIGNER**

[image: 24317906-ffa6-4132-bf03-aac773542d7f-image.png]

How can i make the popup independent from the app window, like this:

[image: 33c43137-9827-4f18-9afc-8c49c3c323c6-image.png]

Or is there a better approach rather than using popup, it would be nice if i were able to move the popup/window around. It still needs to be somehow connected to the main app because it get's data from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Popup in QML appears as a layer on top of the parent window, so it cannot be bigger than the parent window. If you want a separate, top level window, you should use a Window or a Dialog instead.

Comment: `Dialog` is a `Popup`.

Comment: @GrecKo that depends which one you import.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it sorted out. I encapsulated the component i wanted to show inside a window and created it using `Qt.createComponent()`

```
var playListComponent = Qt.createComponent("CustomPlaylist.qml")
var window = playListComponent.createObject(rootWindow)
window.show()
```

The root element of `CustomPlaylist.qml` is a `Window`

[image: Nipsie]